# System attributes set to not display on product page are displaying on product page?

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute

I wrote a simple code for a custom tab to display all atrributes that had a value. But it's returning system attributes that clearly should not be displayed. In the attributes management page in Admin, I checked and triple checked to make sure these attributes were set to NOT display. I refreshed all indexes and flushed all cache, but still showing. Any ideas why this is happening?

Code below, for reference.

```
$_product = $this->getProduct(); 
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
    ->getItems();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute){

    $productAttributeCode=$attribute->getAttributeCode();
    $productAttributeData=$_product->getData($productAttributeCode);

    if ($productAttributeData > ""){
        if ($productAttributeCode != "status"){ 
            echo '<div class="std">';
            echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
            echo ': ';
            //echo $productAttributeCode;
            //echo ': ';
            echo $productAttributeData;
            echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if attribute is visible on frontend:

```
if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFrontend()) {
    (...)
}
```

Comment: That particular function doesn't return any value for me, and I can't find any info on it anywhere on the web :-/

I just hard coded a big long conditional statement to remove all the system ones for now

Comment: Put this: "print_r($attribute->getData());" in foreach loop, and show me what you see.

Comment: Interesting... The output was too long for to post in this comment field, but I think I see something... 

()Array ( [entity_type_id] etc etc etc ---deleted a bunch to fit comment---  [is_visible] => 1  ---deleted a bunch to fit comment---   [is_visible_on_front] => 0 [is_html_allowed_on_front] => 0